# how to make dictionary of a list using dynamic key in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, collections

i am working on a program in which i need to create a dictionary in which i will pass a string and a list at run time and it must create a dictionary using that string as key property.

below is the class :

```
public class Tour
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string City{get;set;}
}
```

here is the function

```
public Dictionary<int,object> GetDictionary(string KeyName, List<object>)
{

}
```

i have an idea that it can be done using reflection but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Are you passing it a list of Tours?

Comment: I imagine the OP expects to be able to call it as `GetDictionary("Id", listOfTour)`..

Comment: Are you want to create Dictionary with the Id of Tour object in the List<object> and tel me what object you will send is it Tour or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No its ust a sample, i am making a generic function.

Comment: why are you passing string keyName and returning dictionary of <int,object> type

Comment: @tariq i want to create a generic function, i needed it in making cache infrastructure

Comment: @VDN I can send object of any type, consider it as a generic function

Comment: Your key in the dictionary needs to be unique, so if you pass in a string as you have , is that string supposed to be used in generating a key for each item?

Comment: @liquidsnake786 yups that in my case i am making sure that i dont have duplicate keys

Comment: @rajansoft1 i understood what you were trying to achieve and have posted an answer which is similar to what you have found, good luck further :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution, thanks for help :)

this is the desired code

```
public class Tour
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string City{get;set;}
}

public Dictionary<int,object> GetDictionary(string KeyName, List<object> list)
{
    var dictionary  = Dictionary<int,object>();
    foreach(var obj in list>
    {
         dictionary.Add(GetPropValue(obj,KeyName);
    }
    return dictionary;
}

public object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
     return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `List<Tour>` in a variable called `tours`, you can get a `Dictionary<int, Tour>` like this:

```
var dictionary = tours.ToDictionary(k => k.Id);
```

**Reference**
[`Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource, TKey> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i am making a generic function, hence i dont know the type and even i dont know the name of the key,

Comment: It doesn't matter.  You can substitute any type you want for `Tour`, but you do need to specify some field from your object as a key in the lambda expression.

Comment: If even it is Generic type why your are sending key as string.Are you want to search the key and return the same key value of Dictonary<int,object>. why  **string KeyName** you mentioned...

Comment: @VDN: I fixed that for you.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: if the object does not contains **id** as Property  then the code which you provided will not useful i think so.
He has to say the Generic object structure so that we can provide the code to help... (Hope u Understand)

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes you are absolutely correct, and VDN what if i want to use this function for some class say Trip and which have Field TripId instead of Id then how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following to return the value of the type within the object

```
public static int GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return (int)src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

Then just cast each element and get the key value and use ToDictionary and within the lamda expression call this function.

```
public Dictionary<int, object> GetDictionary(string KeyName, List<object> list)
{
    return list.ToDictionary(v => GetPropValue(v, KeyName));
}
```